# make tensorflow dataset from huge number of images(*.jpg) and labels(*.mat)

Tags: python, tensorflow, mat-file

I have a huge number of images with their labels (.mat) file (cannot use `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()`) and I want to use `tf.data` API to make a tensorflow dataset out of it.

As I read in the documentation, I can use `tf.data.TextLineDataset` for large number of data(I have to have a txt file with the address of all the images and send the path of the txt file as `tf.data.TextLineDataset` argument).
Then, I can use `map` method to read txt file (`tf.read_file`) decode jpg image (`tf.image.decode_jpeg`) and do some basic transformation on the image.

However, I cannot use `scipy.io.loadmat` in any part of `map` method because I have no string indicating the path to the mat file. All I have is `tf.Tensor`.

I don't think that reading all images and making a TFRecord out of it is that much efficient in this case because then I am basically doing every thing two times. Once, reading the whole images and making TFRecord, and once again, reading TFRecord to make tensorflow dataset.

Any idea how I can resolve this issue?

This is my code:

```
dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(txt_file).map(read_img_and_mat)
```

and then:

```
def read_img_and_mat(path):
    image_string = tf.read_file(path)
    image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=3)
    label = ... # get label from mat file
    return image_decoded, label
```

Comment: So your problem is not knowing the path to your own mat-files? Aren't they the same as the images with some constant string replacement? Are you asking how to manipulate strings in TensorFlow?

Comment: @buzjwa The path to the mat file is known and actually I can get it by replacing '.mat' with '.jpg'. My question is how can I open mat file inside the method and extract the information I need. It seems that I have no string that indicated image path in `read_img_and_mat` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it using `tf.data.from_generator`
The trick I found was to make two separate Dataset (one for mat file and one for the jpg file) and then to combine them using `tf.data.Dataset.zip`

Here is how it works:

```
mat_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(read_mat_file, tf.int64)

def read_mat_file():
    while True:
        with open('mat_addresses.txt', 'r') as input_:
            for line in input_:
                # open file and extract info from it as np.array
                yield tuple(label)  # why tuple? https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13101
```

in order to get the next batch one just have to do:

```
iter = mat_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
sess.run(iter.get_next())
```

however, one can make `img_dataset` and combine it with `mat_dataset` like this:

```
img_dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset('img_addresses.txt').map(read_img)

def read_img(path):
    image_string = tf.read_file(path)
    image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=3)
    return image_decoded

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((mat_dataset, img_dataset))
```

and now, getting next next batch like mentioned.

PS. I have no idea about how efficient the code works in comparison to `feed_dict`